# SQL replace row with matching value

Tags: sql, vb.net, powershell, vb.net-2010, csvde

I'm pulling data out from AD using CSVDE. I have a row named "Managers", which gives distinguished name when pulling data. I somehow replaced that value with employee's ID.
I executed and got

> CN=Manager1,OU=Container,DC=DomainController

Need to replace whole thing with Manager1's employee ID. I can either do it in PowerShell or VB, if necessary.

Comment: you should provide some sample code so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell and the ActiveDirectory module:

```
Import-CSV <csvfile> |
  foreach {
           $_.Manager = (Get-Aduser $_.Manager -Properties EmployeeID).EmployeeID
          } |
              Export-CSV <csvfile> -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: this is what I'm getting

Get-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity' to the target. Exception setting "Identity": "Cannot validate argument on parameter: 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an 
argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again."

Comment: Can you post sample data from your .csv?

Comment: I can verify that the issues are happening because a lot of the entries don't have any data in that field. Some people don't have managers. I made a test csv and tried your code and it ran, but the output file was blank

Comment: I got the output to work but it is basically taking each manager once and listing them in a separate CSV file. I need it to replace their DN name in the original CSV file to their employee ID